# Set up Cypress IO to work with dotenv on Quasar Framework

Tags: vue.js, cypress, quasar-framework, dotenv

I'm using Quasar framework and just after I've added [quasar-dotenv](https://github.com/CarbonoDev/quasar-dotenv) package I realized that e2e tests not working.

[image: Getting this error on every start]

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

This error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

Check your console for the stack trace or click this message to see where it originated from.
    at Object.config (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:141291:34)
    at Object.746.eslint (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:150393:36)
    at o (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:1:265)
    at http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:1:316
    at Object.747.../../../../quasar.conf.js (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:150535:35)
    at o (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:1:265)
    at r (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:1:431)
    at http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=test/cypress/integration/home/init.spec.js-312:1:460
```

I've tried to set up the Cypress environment by adding the `test/cypress/plugins/cypress.env.json` file with some data, as well as changing the `test/cypress/plugins/index.js` file in the same folder, by following this [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api.html#Usage) as it was suggested [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1358):

```js
const env = require('quasar-dotenv').config()

module.exports = (on, config) => {

  // config.env.API_URL = 'http://example.com' // not working
  config.env = env

  // Chrome:: Hack for shaking AUT. Cypress Issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1620
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      args.push('--disable-blink-features=RootLayerScrolling');
      return args;
    }
    return true;
  });

  return config
};
```

- MacOS Catalina
- Cypress v3.5.0
- Chrome v77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer because I am unfamiliar with `quasar-dotenv`. Have you tried the official quasar dotenv app extension? https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-dotenv or, alternatively, another official app extension, but less opinionated than dotenv wrappers: https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-qenv

Comment: Oh, there's an official package... I guess I was looking for it on a wrong place... 
Yes, that's it, it works now. Thanks.

Comment: It also turns out, the one you were using was made for Quasar v0.17